# Adding child nodes using c# Xdocument class

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <file:Situattion xmlns:file="test">

  <file:Properties>

</file:Situattion>
```

I would like to add the child element file:Character using xDocument.So that my final xml would be like given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <file:Situattion xmlns:file="test">

   <file:Characters>

     <file:Character file:ID="File0">
     <file:Value>value0</file:Value>
     <file:Description>
      Description0 
     </file:Description>
     </file:Character>

 <file:Character file:ID="File1">
     <file:Value>value1</file:Value>
     <file:Description>
     Description1
     </file:Description>
     </file:Character>

     </file:Characters>
```

Code in c# i tried using Xdocument class is given below.

```
        XNamespace ns = "test";
        Document = XDocument.Load(Folderpath + "\\File.test");

        if (Document.Descendants(ns + "Characters") != null)
        {

            Document.Add(new XElement(ns + "Character"));
        }
        Document.Save(Folderpath + "\\File.test");
```

At line "`Document.Add(new XElement(ns + "Character"));`", I am getting an error:

`"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."`.

How can I add the node under "`file:Characters`".

Comment: have you looked into using `XPATH` or `XQuery` also look at the `->Related` Link located to the right side of this current page, lots of working examples for you to investigate

Comment: @DJKRAZE: There's no need to use XPath or XQuery here at all, and I don't believe they'd even make the code simpler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're trying to add an extra `file:Character` element *directly* into the root. You don't want to do that - you want to add it under the `file:Characters` element, presumably.

Also note that `Descendants()` will *never* return null - it will return an empty sequence if there are no matching elements. So you want:

```
var ns = "test";
var file = Path.Combine(folderPath, "File.test");
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
// Or var characters = document.Root.Element(ns + "Characters")
var characters = document.Descendants(ns + "Characters").FirstOrDefault();
if (characters != null)
{
    characters.Add(new XElement(ns + "Character");
    doc.Save(file);
}
```

Note that I've used more conventional naming, `Path.Combine`, and also moved the `Save` call so that you'll only end up saving if you've actually made a change to the document.

Comment: What is the type of "document" object.?

Comment: getting an error "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

Comment: @user1654136: `doc` is `XDocument`. And if you're getting that error, that suggests you're using `"file:Character"` as the local name instead of `ns + "Character"`, or something similar. You shouldn't have that problem in the code I've provided.

Comment: How can i add file:ID="File0" and <file:Value>value0</file:Value>
using the above code

Comment: @user1654136: Use `new XAttribute(ns + "ID", "File0")` and `new XElement(ns + "Value", "value0")`. Basically you use `ns` for the namespace - you *don't* put the alias into the localname.

Answer (score 8):

```
    Document.Root.Element("Characters").Add(new XElement("Character", new XAttribute("ID", "File0"), new XElement("Value", "value0"), new XElement("Description")),
        new XElement("Character", new XAttribute("ID", "File1"), new XElement("Value", "value1"), new XElement("Description")));
```

**Note:** I have not included the namespace for brevity. You have to add those.