# LINQ to xml: result based on attributes

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, linq

I have an XML similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schedule>

<Aircraft mdy="Thursday, September 1, 2016" Destination="London"  
  Source="Greece" ID="B747">
 <FROM>GRE</FROM>
 <TO>LON</TO>
 <Miles>3000</Miles>
 </Aircraft>

 <Aircraft mdy="Thursday, September 1, 2016" Destination="New York"  
  Source="Greece" ID="B747">
  <FROM>GRE</FROM>
  <TO>IT</TO>
  <Miles>20000</Miles>
  </Aircraft>

 <Aircraft mdy="Thursday, September 1, 2016" Destination="Mykonos"  
  Source="Athens" ID="A320">
  <FROM>ATH</FROM>
  <TO>MYK</TO>
  <Miles>300</Miles>
  </Aircraft>

  </schedule>
```

Please help me on the below query. My LINQ experience is limited and at a novice level.

```
var p = from a in reservation.Descendants("Aircrafts")
        where a.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("B747")
        ...
        change array contents
```

I want to dynamically change the content of the array below based on ID attribute. For instance if ID=="B747" seats[100], else if ID=="A320" seats[200] etc.

```
static int p= 100;
public static bool[] seats;
seats = new bool[p];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just set `p` you can do:

```
var p = (from element in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants("Aircraft")
         let type = element.Attribute("ID").Value
         where type.Equals("B747")
         select type == "B747" ? 100 :
                type == "A320" ? 200 : 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can also do something like this: (and then load it at the beginning and use it each time)

```
var seatsForModel = (from element in reservation.Descendants("Aircraft")
                     let type = element.Attribute("ID").Value
                     select new
                     {
                        AircraftModel = type,
                        Seats = type == "B747" ? 100 :
                                type == "A320" ? 200 : 0
                     }).Distinct().ToDictionary(key => key.AircraftModel, value => value.Seats);

// Output: [B747, 100],
//         [A320, 200]

bool[] seatsTaken = new bool[seatsForModel["B747"]];
```

I create a `Dictionary<string,int>` of aircraft model to the number of seats it has and then you can use it to create your `bool[]`.

Though... I a **better design** would be to have somewhere a mapping between the model and the number of seats and then to join it to the items from the xml

---

As for not being able to access `p` in the other function wrap the linq in a function and call it from the other function:

```
public int GetNumberOfSeats(string aircraftModel)
{
    var p = (from element in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants("Aircraft")
             let type = element.Attribute("ID").Value
             where type.Equals(aircraftModel)
             select type == "B747" ? 100 :
                    type == "A320" ? 200 : 0).FirstOrDefault();
    return p;
}

public void assignFirstClass()
{
    var p = GetNumberOfSeats("B747");
    bool[] seats = new bool[p];

    //Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Hello Gilad, thank you very much for your help, currently i'm on mobile, I will try your solution on my pc. Cheers, mate!

Comment: Goodmorning, your solution seems wonderful but the array is not visible from functions.

Comment: It says The name 'seats' does not exist in the current context'. What about second approach? I haven't tried dictionary yet, as i cannot understand how to use it, I'm still googling on it. What do you mean to use it each time?

Comment: @user3136729 - see update about how to have p for the other function. I suggest read more into static and when to use it. About the dictionary you can have a local variable that will store it and then every time you need the seats you address it instead of again accessing the file and reading from it

Comment: @user3136729 - Also about the error with `p` I suggest going more into learning procedural and oop programming before having linq and reading files and so

Comment: I'm now trying your code, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3136729 - Did this answer help you solve your original question?

Comment: Yes! awesome reply (+1 for that). thanks so much. One more question. How can I save array seat position to an xelement? something like XDocument p = XDocument.Load("Reservation.xml) p.Element("Reservation").Add    new XElement("Seat", positionOfTheArray.Text)

Comment: @user3136729 - Glad it helped. About your other question we should not have followup questions in the comments but it should be a new question. A place to start might be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916788/adding-child-nodes-using-c-sharp-xdocument-class)

Comment: Hello again, you help is really valuable, I asked a question but nobody helped me. Can you have a look please? It's about how to call a void method inside a linq query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306498/linq-xml-calling-c-sharp-method?noredirect=1#comment65947213_39306498