# linq XML calling c# method

Tags: c#, xml, linq, function, methods

based on this XML

```
 <schedule>

 <flight="A01">
-<Aircraft mdy="Thursday, September 1, 2016" Destination="Mykonos"    
  Source="Athens" ID="A320">
  <FROM>ATH</FROM>
  <TO>MYK</TO>
  <Miles>300</Miles>
  </Aircraft>
  </flight>

  </schedule>
```

I have the following code

```
  XDocument reservation = XDocument.Load("schedulemanager.xml");

        var r = (from element in XDocument.Load("schedulemanager.xml").Descendants("Aircraft")
                 let type = element.Attribute("mdy").Value
                 select type == dtArrival.Text ? MessageBox.Show("Dates are same") : type != dtArrival.Text ? MessageBox.Show("Dates not matching") : 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

The first query compares datepicker date that chosen by the user, with the mdy attribute "Thursday, September 1, 2016". If dates are same, a message box appears. This works fine. But when I'm trying to call a method (returns void) an error message appears "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'void' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' "

I want something like this

```
var r = (from element in    
XDocument.Load("schedulemanager.xml").Descendants("Aircraft")
                 let type = element.Attribute("mdy").Value
                 select type == dtArrival.Text ? makeReservation()
```

Also, how can I have multiple if statements in linq? Something like

```
 if select mdy==dateTimePicker && id == flightID && something==sth...then
```

Another question is how a variable can be cancelled/deallocated after a time limit? For instance, how reservation can be cancelled after two days from booking. I have read about timestamp but I don't know if I'm right.

Thanks in advance, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First you are missing the ':' (else) part of the conditional.  You are calling makeReservation() when true but nothing for the else.  Something like this should work : select mdy==dateTimePicker && id == flightID ? makeReservation() : null

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's just an example I didn't miss anything. makeReservation() :null  does not work.